# Как записать в .xlsx файл таблицы с заголовком?

Tags: python, pandas, excel, style

Использую такой код:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(self.table)
df.sort_values(by=['id'], ascending=False)
df.style.set_caption("Заголовок таблицы")
df.to_excel(path+"test.xlsx", sheet_name="sheet111", index=False)
```

Но заголовок не появляется.

Comment: а что вы подразумеваете под заголовком в Excel файле?

Comment: @MaxU на первой строчке во всю ширину таблицы ячейка с текстом названия таблицы

Comment: set_caption работает видимо только с HTML ((

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В [документации](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.set_caption.html) явно указано, что объект `Styler.style.set_caption` устанавливает текст в HTML элементе `<caption>`:

> Set the text added to a `<caption>` HTML element.

Соответственно этот метод не будет работать для Excel файла.

Comment: Спасибо, значит нету нативного способа вставить заголовок таблицы в excel

Comment: @helldrg ну почему же? https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_merge1.html

Comment: я создал ексель файл с таблицей функцией `to_excel` а после открыл файл как раз через тот модуль, добавил строку и настроил ее. Куда проще было бы если работал бы set_caption в excel файлах